# Object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Basically I am passing current db to the procedure, taking data from #clients_pom and updating it, but...

> Msg 7357, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Cannot process the object "SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC WBANKA_KBBL2.dbo.sp_kbbl_WachLista_Priprema '2017-09-30', '2017-09-30', 0". The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "(null)" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Datum varchar(20)
SET @Datum= '2017-09-30'

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##WL_Klijenti') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##WL_Klijenti

 SELECT @SQL = '
    SELECT * 
      INTO ##WL_Klijenti
   FROM  OPENROWSET (''SQLOLEDB'',''Server=
  (local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;'',''SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC 
  ' + DB_NAME()+'.dbo.sp_kbbl_WachLista_Priprema ''''' + @Datum + ''''', 
  ''''' + @Datum + ''''', 0'')
  AS tbl'

  EXEC(@SQL)

  UPDATE C
  SET C.watchListStatus = '1'
  FROM #clients_pom AS C
  INNER JOIN ##WL_Klijenti AS WL ON WL.mbr = C.registrationNumber

  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##WL_Klijenti') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##WL_Klijenti
```

Comment: This looks like your previous question took a turn for the worse. Global temp tables are very problematic as they introduce concurrency issues. I have to ask why you are trying to use OPENQUERY when the procedure is in the same database? Does your procedure honestly change so frequently that you don't know the output at run time?

Comment: It is my 10th hour at work and I am lagging a bit, can you provide any possible solution to this

Comment: Honestly you should probably get some rest before you make more decisions that you will regret later. Why can't you just create a temp table based on the output of your procedure? Then populate it with your procedure. There really is no need for openquery and all this complicated stuff you have going on here.